# How can I make "has_object_permission( )" work?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, user-permissions

I'm trying to create an object level permission for a user. The structure of my ddbb model is the following one:

- A Teacher owns a Classroom (id_teacher ForeignKey)
- A Classroom owns some Students (id_classroom ForeignKey)

I want to let the access to Student information just for the teacher who owns the classroom where the Students are registered.

Here are the API code and the permission code:

```
class StudentAPI(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [GetStudentPermission, ]

    def get(self, request):
        student_ = Student.objects.get(username=request.GET['username'])
        s_student_ = StudentSerializer(student_)
        return Response(s_student_.data)
```

```
class GetStudentPermission(BasePermission):
    message = 'La información de este estudiante está restringida para usted'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        cls_ = Classroom.objects.filter(id=obj.id_classroom.id).first()
        tch_ = Teacher.objects.get(classroom=cls_)
        user_ = User.objects.get(id=tch_.id_user.id)
        return bool(user_ == request.user)
```

It seems like permission classes is not working at all because I can access to the information of each student being registered with any user account.
Thank you beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the note in the section [Custom permissions [DRF docs]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions):

> The instance-level `has_object_permission` method will only be called
> if the view-level `has_permission` checks have already passed. Also
> note that in order for the instance-level checks to run, the view code
> should explicitly call `.check_object_permissions(request, obj)`. If
> you are using the generic views then this will be handled for you by
> default. (Function-based views will need to check object permissions
> explicitly, raising `PermissionDenied` on failure.)

Since you override `get` and implement it yourself `check_object_permissions` is never called, you can either do it yourself:

```
class StudentAPI(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [GetStudentPermission, ]

    def get(self, request):
        student_ = Student.objects.get(username=request.GET['username'])
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, student)
        s_student_ = StudentSerializer(student_)
        return Response(s_student_.data)
```

OR better yet your implementation of get is not much different than the builtin implementation that `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` already has, so you can forego overriding `get` and actually use the view directly:

```
class StudentAPI(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    permission_classes = [GetStudentPermission, ]
```